# Installing RApache in Ubuntu 16.04 Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu): I get some errors

Tags: r, apache, ubuntu, rapache

I am trying to install RApache in Ubuntu 16.04 Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) but I get some errors:

1- First when i install some packages:

sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev apache2-mpm-prefork libapreq2-dev r-base-dev

I get an error message:

Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package apache2-prefork-dev
E: Package 'apache2-mpm-prefork' has no installation candidate

When I try

debuild -us -uc

I get the message:

This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of libapache2-mod-r-base_1.2.8.orig.tar.gz, libapache2-mod-r-base_1.2.8.orig.tar.bz2,
libapache2-mod-r-base_1.2.8.orig.tar.lzma,  libapache2-mod-r-base_1.2.8.orig.tar.xz or rapache.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n)

I decide for yes but it does not work, I get:

dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package libapache2-mod-r-base
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.2.8-xenial0
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution xenial0
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Jeroen Ooms 
 dpkg-source --before-build rapache
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: apache2-dev
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed

Is there anybody who can help me please?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a whole bunch of files. See [the official documentation](https://linuxfr.org/news/sortie-de-it-edit-integrated-terminals-editor-2-91) for preparing the proper directory structure, suitable for packaging. See [this package source](https://bitbucket.org/yassinphilip/fwomaj/src) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for your information but the issue was posted nearly one year ago!! It already works fine. Thanks!